# Acessar modelo de dados VUE por outro script

Tags: javascript, html, orientação-a-objetos, vue.js

Bom tenho um modelo de dados com as seguintes informações no vuejs

```
  graficos: {
     data : {
          labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
          series: [
            [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
          ]
     },

     options : {
         width: 600,
         height: 300
     },
```

na minha pagina html tenho isso

```
<div id="app">

  <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>

</div>
    <script>
    new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', this.graficos.data, this.graficos.options);
</script>
```

porem ocorre um erro `" cannot read property 'data' of undefined "`
como faço pra acessar modelos de dados do vuejs atraves de um outro script ,

Obs: preciso colocar isso `new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', this.graficos.data, this.graficos.options);` na minha pagina html porque não sei como faria para colocar este metodo dentro do Modelo de dados do VUE porque se eu fosse colocar um metodo teria que ficar chamando ele